# ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC creating roles and admin user

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

I am new to ASP and need some help. I making asp.net core 3.1 mvc.I am trying to add three types of users:

1. Buyer
2. Seller
3. Admin

I want to create the three roles and an Admin user in the Startup class, but I can't do it. Can you some tell me how to do it? I am not sure if it is relevant, but I am using MySQL database and not the default one.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can create a table name Authentication contain columns: ID, UserName, Role, Active

Or refer here: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/asmabegam/Asp-Net-mvc-5-security-and-creating-user-role/